# Making QComboBox widgets distinguishable in a for loop using PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I'm having trouble with an application that creates a grid of `QComboBox` widgets (see picture below). I use a `for` loop to create the elements of the grid.

QComboBox grid layout

[image]

I would like to be able to treat each QComboBox separately. Here is the code without attempts to do so:

```
grid = QGridLayout()
combos = [
'1', '1', '1', '', '1', 
'1', '1', '1', '', '1',
'1', '1', '1', '', '1',
'1', '1', '1', '', '1']

positions = [(i,j) for i in range(5) for j in range(5)]
for position, dcombo in zip(positions, combos):
    if dcombo == '':
        continue
    combo = QComboBox()

    for x in range(0, 30):
        combo.addItem(QIcon("/icons/%d.PNG" % x),"")

    combo.setFixedSize(120,100)
    combo.setIconSize(QSize(100,100))
    grid.addWidget(combo, *position)

    comboList['combo{0}'.format(position)] = position
```

Here is my attempt, and the point at which I am currently stuck:

```
grid = QGridLayout()
combos = [
'1', '1', '1', '', '1', 
'1', '1', '1', '', '1',
'1', '1', '1', '', '1',
'1', '1', '1', '', '1']

comboList = {}

positions = [(i,j) for i in range(5) for j in range(5)]
for position, drawcombo in zip(positions, combos):
    if drawcombo == '':
        continue
    combo = QComboBox()

    for x in range(0, 30): #
        combo.addItem(QIcon("absolver deck reviewer/icons/%d.PNG" % x),"")

    combo.setFixedSize(120,100)
    combo.setIconSize(QSize(100,100))
    grid.addWidget(combo, *position)

    comboList['combo{0}'.format(position)] = position
    combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda: self.logChange(comboList['combo{0}'.format(position)]))

def logChange(self, currentCombo):
    sender = self.sender()
    print(str(currentCombo) + ' was changed')
```

The print() method only ever returns the last position in the list (in this case, the (3, 4) tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the position variable changes this is overwritten by it only prints the last one, if you want it not to be overwritten you must pass it as an argument to the lambda function, besides. And for this you must also pass as an argument the variable that sends the signal, in your case use the following:

```
combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(
    lambda ix, p=position: self.logChange(comboList['combo{0}'.format(p)]))
```

Comment: This works, many thanks!
I now face the problem of editing the combo inside the logChange function. I do not see any way to use the position tuple to edit it right from it.

Comment: I plan to add different types of ComboBox and apply changes to the grid whenever an item is selected. In this case, I would need a way to replace a QComboBox with another one, based on its coordinates.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I fully understand. Are you saying I should create another QGridLayout in the logChange() function to replace the QComboBox with another QComboBox? Or should I pass the grid to the logChange function to edit it there?